# Unable to run apt-get --purge autoremove

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

When I ran a script to stop two services, my Ubuntu 16.4 LTS crashed.  After googling, I found that, there are many linux images in my sytem.  By default it was using
`linux-image-4.4.0-187-generic`

I changed that to
`linux-image-4.4.0-185-generic`
during booting in **Advanced Options**.

Now, the system is fine, but  whenever I reboot, it is going back to the previous image and creating problem.

I need to create a new `grub.cfg` file, but I need to purge all the unwanted linux images except `4.4.0-185`.
When I run `sudo apt --purge autoremove` command, it is throwing the following error.

```
(Reading database ... 746033 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-pil.imagetk_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pil.imagetk:amd64.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pil.imagetk:amd64.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pil.imagetk_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pil.imagetk:amd64.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pil.imagetk:amd64.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python-pil_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pil:amd64.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pil:amd64.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pil_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pil:amd64.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pil:amd64.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python-imaging_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-imaging.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-imaging.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-imaging_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-imaging.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-imaging.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pil.imagetk_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pil_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-imaging_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am clueless.  When I used, `boot-repair`, it gave me a log file, which you can find it here.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mkvkty2BwH/.

Please help me as I don't want to waste my data and bring back the system as usual.

Comment: Install the `python-minimal` package, which includes the missing `pyclean`. Then try again. On newer releases of Ubuntu, it would be `python3-minimal`.

Comment: I think there lies the problem.  By default, I have python 2 installed, and later for my purposes, I installed Python 3.  Now, there is a confusion between these two.  I tried changing `/usr/bin/python` to python3 and later reverted back fearing some unwanted consequences.  I need a solution to clean my python code base so this conflict doesn't arise in the future.

Comment: Stock Ubuntu 16.04 has both Py2 and Py3 installed (2016 was the middle of the 2-to-3 transition). Apt still used Py2 in 2016. System service like apt NEED the original version of Py2 and Py3 that came with the system; they don't work with different versions. Revert your changes. Revert your newly-installed versions. Don't point `python` at Py3.